# Getting error with binding event in c#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a button in the design page with name BtnCall;

and I am trying to add the event like this

```
public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();
    BtnCall.Click = new System.EventHandler(this.OnBtnCallClicked);
}
```

but i am getting an error

```
/home/bonnie/workstation/voip/voip/MainWindow.cs(11,11): Error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer (CS0131) (voip)
```

Comment: I tried this but, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to an event ([Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx)), you need to use the `+=` syntax.

I invite you to read the [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: @souparnomajumder Would you care to explain what you tried and what did not work ?